# can't make top-nav bar

Tags: css, html

i tried to make a top nav bar. why my version is different from the w3s version, I cant find my mistake.

this is the css code and the html code

```css
.logo {
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #a80664;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: #a80664;
}

.topnav-menu {
  float: left;
}

.topnav-menu a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav-menu a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ff0094;
}

.topnav-menu a.active {
  {
    color: #a80664;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS STYLESHEET LINK -->

  <!-- MY CUSTOM CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">
  <li>
    <div class="logo"><a>LOGO</a></div>
  </li>
  <ul class="topnav-menu">
    <li><a class="active" href="#Home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Kategori">KATEGORI</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

With those code I can't make a top nav bar like this
 [this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl0Es.png)

what kind of mistake did i do?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: share your code instead of sharing the image...

Comment: Please post your code, and what you are expecting, and what result you are getting.

Comment: Your navbar does not work because your HTML is illegal. `<li>` are the only valid children of `<ul>`, in HTML. Also, make sure you read [Ask] before asking again. You must make sure your questions are also useful for others, not just for you. If you don't do that, people will be less likely to help.

Comment: Create a [mcve] in the question itself. We can only inspect `code`, not images. Also note questions on problems created by minor typographical errors are off-topic on SO, as they are unlikely to help future visitors. Use an HTML validator before asking.

Comment: sorry, my bad guys

I've edited it

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your logo before  tag and you have to wrap

in 
    and you have to wrap your all code in side

```
 <nav>
     <div class="logo">
        <a href="brand"><img src="imagepath"></a>
      </div>
       <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>`enter code here`
          **strong text**<li>About</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>
```